# WooCommerce Show Product Total Sales after Custom a Date in Frontend

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, woocommerce, product

I want to show product total sales after custom date:

I have this code, but I would like to custom it for showing only the total sales after a custom date for example `05/26/2016`

```
function total_sales()
{
    global $product;
    $units_sold = get_post_meta(206, 'total_sales', true);
    echo '<p>' . sprintf(__('Units Sold: %s', 'woocommerce'), $units_sold) . '</p>';
}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> `total_sales` holds the total sales count of all time, So you need to
>   write custom query to get sold count between specific date.

```
//woocommerce get total sale count of a product after a specific data
function wh_get_total_sold_by_product_id($date_from, $product_id)
{
    global $wpdb;
    $date_to = date('Y-m-d');

    $sql = "
    SELECT COUNT(*) AS sale_count
    FROM {$wpdb->prefix}woocommerce_order_items AS order_items
    INNER JOIN {$wpdb->prefix}woocommerce_order_itemmeta AS order_meta ON order_items.order_item_id = order_meta.order_item_id
    INNER JOIN {$wpdb->posts} AS posts ON order_meta.meta_value = posts.ID
    WHERE order_items.order_item_type = 'line_item'
    AND order_meta.meta_key = '_product_id'
    AND order_meta.meta_value = %d
    AND order_items.order_id IN (
        SELECT posts.ID AS post_id
        FROM {$wpdb->posts} AS posts
        WHERE posts.post_type = 'shop_order'
            AND posts.post_status IN ('wc-completed','wc-processing')
            AND DATE(posts.post_date) BETWEEN %s AND %s
    )
    GROUP BY order_meta.meta_value";

    return $wpdb->get_var($wpdb->prepare($sql, $product_id, $date_from, $date_to));
}
```

*Code goes in [`functions.php`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Functions_File_Explained) file of your active child theme (or theme). Or also in any plugin php files.*

**USAGE**

```
//$count = wh_get_total_sold_by_product_id($my_custom_date, $product_id);
$count = wh_get_total_sold_by_product_id('2016-05-26', 56);
```

Please Note: *All the date are in `Y-m-d` format.*

**Code is tested and works.**

Hope this helps!

Comment: Uncaught ArgumentCountError: Too few arguments to function wh_get_total_sold_by_product_id(), 1 passed in /app/public/wp-includes/class-wp-hook.php on line 286


I get this when add to functions.php file

Comment: @FoamyMedia: are you passing both the argument, i.e. date and product ID?